# Checkboxes not binding to tags they create on DOM jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, checkbox

I have created a modal with checkboxes that when checked, are added to the DOM. The issues that I am having that I have been trying to troubleshoot for days are that whether the checkboxes are checked or unchecked, the tag is added to the DOM, not just when checked.

I also cannot figure out how to remove the tag from the DOM when the associated checkbox is unchecked. I have the amount of checkboxes that are able to be checked max out at 6, which is what I am looking to have, but is there a way to max the amount of child divs within a parent div there could be? That way theres another safeguard to fall back on so that no more than 6 tags can be selected at one time?

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/co5w7c9j/ with what I have, hopefully I explained enough without making it sound too confusing.

Below is my jquery that I have written thus far, I think I am missing a step somewhere to achieve what I am looking for.

Thank you for taking the time to look through my code.

```
// When specilaty is checked, add tag to profile page
$('[name=specialty]').click(function() {
    $newTag = $("<div class='specTag'>" + $(this).attr('value') + "<div class='xOut'>x</div></div>");
    $(this).attr('value');
    $('.Specialties').append($newTag);

    /*  if ($('.Specialties > .specTag').has(('[name=specialty]:checked').attr('value'))) {
        $('.Specialties > .specTag').has((this).txt()).remove();  
        } */

    // Count number of checkboxes selected and display in modal
    var increment = 0;
    $('[name=specialty]:checked').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            increment++;
        } else {
            increment--;
        }
        $('#specCount').html(increment);
    });

    // Disable checkboxes when 6 (maximum) are selected
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=specialty]").click(function() {
        var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=specialty]:checked").length >= 6;
        $("input[type=checkbox][name=specialty]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
    });

    // Create array of checked items - add on checked - remove on uncheck
    specialtyArray = $('[name=specialty]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();

        // if item is in the array, then remove it from the DOM
        if (jQuery.inArray($('[name=specialty]:checked').val(), specialtyArray) > -1) {}
    });
    console.log(specialtyArray.get());

});

// When Specialties modal closes, uncheck all checked boxes, reset count
$(document.body).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.modal-body > #updateSpecForm > .columns').children().removeAttr('checked');
    $('#specCount').html(0);
})

// Fade out specialty tags when x is clicked
$(document.body).on('click', '.xOut', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to compartmentalize code by setting parts of it into functions so that conditional aspects are easier to read through  .

The biggest issue in your code was not testing if checkboxes were checked or not in the click handler.

Since the checkbox needs to do the same as the click on new tag does when it is unchecked, all logic flows through the change event of checkbox. Note that the click handler on `X` of tag triggers the change also

```
var maxChecked = 6;

// use change handler on checkboxes, will get triggered also below in another click handler
var $checkboxes = $('[name=specialty]').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(this.checked ){
        addTag( value);
    }else{
       removeTag( value ); 
    }    
     checkBoxStatus();

});

function removeTag(checkBoxValue){
    /* we stored the checkbox value as data attribute,  use that to filter*/
    $('.specTag').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('value') === checkBoxValue;
    }).slideUp(function(){
       $(this).remove(); 
    })
}

function addTag( checkBoxValue){
     $newTag = $("<div class='specTag'>" + checkBoxValue + "<div class='xOut'>x</div></div>");
    /* store the value in elment data so we can reference back to checkbox */
    $newTag.data('value', checkBoxValue);
    $('.Specialties').append($newTag);

}
/* use this to both disable and enable checkboxes */
function checkBoxStatus(){
    var limitReached = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === maxChecked;
    $checkboxes.not(':checked').prop('disabled',limitReached);    
}

$(document.body).on('click', '.xOut', function () {
    var $element = $(this).parent(),
        $checkbox = $checkboxes.filter(function(){
            return this.value === $element.data('value');
         /* trigger change to remove element and reset disabled checkboxes */
        }).prop('checked',false).change();


});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gktqcrjm/1)**</kbd>

Comment: thank you for your help and giving some explanation to the logic. I knew I was close, Im newer with javascript and jquery so I still am fumbling a bit. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
// When specilaty is checked, add tag to profile page
$('input[name=specialty]').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;

  //if checked add a new item else remove item.
  if (this.checked) {
    var $newTag = $("<div class='specTag'>" + value + "<div class='xOut'>x</div></div>").attr('data-id', value);
    $('.Specialties').append($newTag);
  } else {
    //use the attribute value which is the same as the input value to find out the item to be removed
    $('.Specialties').find('div.specTag[data-id="' + value + '"]').remove()
  }

  //cache the result since it is used multiple times
  var $checked = $('input[name=specialty]:checked');

  // Count number of checkboxes selected and display in modal
  var increment = $checked.length;
  $('#specCount').html(increment);

  // Disable checkboxes when 6 (maximum) are selected
  var bol = increment.length >= 6;
  //use prop instead of attr to set the disabled state
  $("input[type=checkbox][name=specialty]").not(":checked").prop("disabled", bol);

  // Create array of checked items - add on checked - remove on uncheck
  var specialtyArray = $checked.map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(specialtyArray.get());

});

// When Specialties modal closes, uncheck all checked boxes, reset count
$(document.body).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $('.modal-body > #updateSpecForm > .columns').children().prop('checked', false);
  $('#specCount').html(0);
})

// Fade out specialty tags when x is clicked
$(document.body).on('click', '.xOut', function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  //uncheck the corresponding checkbox
  $('input[name=specialty][value="' + $(this).closest('.specTag').attr('data-id') + '"]').prop('checked', false)
});
```

```css
.Specialties {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 350px;
  height: 135px;
  margin-left: 249px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.specTag {
  background-color: #51b848;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  height 30px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.xOut {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="GET" id="updateSpecForm">
  <!-- ATHLETIC TRAINER OPTIONS -->
  <div class="columns" id="athleticTrainer">
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Boot Camp" />Boot Camp
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Children's Fitness" />Children's Fitness
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Circuit Training" />Circuit Training
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Core Training" />Core Training
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Cycling/Spinning" />Cycling/Spinning
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Dance" />Dance
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Flexibility/Balance" />Flexibility/Balance
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Meal Planning" />Meal Planning
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Men's Fitness" />Men's Fitness
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialty" value="Women's Fitness" />Women's Fitness
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="Specialties">
    <!-- SHOW BELOW DIV ONLY IF LOGGED IN -->
    <!-- <div class="updateOn"><a href="#updateSpecialties" class="updateSpecialties" role="button" data-toggle="modal">+ Update My Specialties</a></div> -->
    <!-- ***PRO CAN ADD UP TO 6 SPECIALY TAGS*** -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you @Arun P Johny, This is way more along the lines of whatI am trying to achieve. Thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/co5w7c9j/1/

```
// When specilaty is checked, add tag to profile page
$('[name=specialty]').click(function() {

$newTag = $("<div class='specTag'>" + $(this).attr('value') + "<div class='xOut'>x</div></div>");
$(this).attr('value');
$('.Specialties').append($newTag);  

EnableDisableCheck();


// Create array of checked items - add on checked - remove on uncheck
specialtyArray = $('[name=specialty]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();

    // if item is in the array, then remove it from the DOM
    if (jQuery.inArray($('[name=specialty]:checked').val(), specialtyArray) > -1) { 
    }
});
console.log(specialtyArray.get());

});

// When Specialties modal closes, uncheck all checked boxes, reset count
    $(document.body).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $('.modal-body > #updateSpecForm > .columns').children().removeAttr('checked');
    $('#specCount').html(0);    
})

// Fade out specialty tags when x is clicked
$(document.body).on('click', '.xOut', function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).parent().remove();   
    var text = $(this).parent().text();
    $('[name=specialty]:checked').filter(function () {

        return text.indexOf($(this).val()) > - 1;

    }).removeAttr('checked');
    EnableDisableCheck();
}); 

function EnableDisableCheck(){
if($('[name=specialty]:checked').length >=5)
{
$('[name=specialty]').attr("disabled","disabled");
}
else
{
$('[name=specialty]').removeAttr("disabled");
}
}
```